# can not resolve variable volley

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley

I am trying to send data on wamp phpmyadmin.. I am using volley library to send data in mysql database on local host, but the volley in my code is in red color giving error (can not resolve the symbol volley). I've added volley library in libs folder but still the problem is there.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.makeaccount);


    emailHint = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailHint);
    userNameHint = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UserHint);
    passHint = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterPass);
    reenterHint = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Reenter);

    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BACK);
    ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OK);
    requestQueue = volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
```

The key word (volley) in the last line is red although I,ve added the volley library in the libs folder. Also added the volley library in the gradle file but still its not working..

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.0'
```

Can any one have the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Repository `com.mcxiaoke.volley` is basically a fork of Google library, so I suppose you can use only official version. Please also note, that according to the [mcxiaoke/android-volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley) `READ.ME` :

> (...) this project is deprecated and no longer being maintained, please use official version from jCenter.
>
> `compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'`